# Enthought Canopy package manager upgrade/install error

Tags: package, enthought, canopy

I have installed v1.7.2.3327 and have been unable to get the Package Manager to update or install packages.  It shows 11 Updates available, but none update correctly.  I have also tried to install statsmodels but have encountered errors as well.  I am running in Windows 10 Build 10240.  As an example, when attempting to install statsmodels 0.6.1-16 I repeatedly get an Install error - Try again.  The History shows the following:

Warming up...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_dashboard\packman\package_action_worker.py", line 54, in run
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_dashboard\packman\package_action.py", line 193, in execute
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_dashboard\packman\packman.py", line 352, in <lambda>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_dashboard\packman\packman.py", line 889, in _install
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_platform\cpython_packages_manager.py", line 85, in install_package
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_platform\enpkg_api.py", line 106, in install_package
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_platform\enpkg_api.py", line 181, in _execute_in_subprocess
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_platform\enpkg_api.py", line 216, in _propogate_progress_events
IOError: [Errno 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

The same history shows up for Upgrade apptools 4.4.0-2 to 4.4.0-3

Comment: This is an unfamiliar error; will investigate further on your support ticket.